# Stripe React C# I am trying to send an amount from from frontend to my backend when creating a payment intent but receiving a 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, reactjs, stripe-payments

```
var amount = {
      amount: cart.CartPrice +
      cart.CartPrice * 0.06625 +
      props.fee +
      props.tipAmount.amount
    }

    JSON.stringify(amount);

    //Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
    axios.post(
      "https://localhost:5001/api/Checkout/create-payment-intent",
      amount,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    ).then((res) => res.json())
    .then(({ clientSecret }) => setClientSecret(clientSecret));
```

In my frontend I am creating an amount and trying to send it to my backends controller.

```
[HttpPost("create-payment-intent")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> CreateCheckoutSession([FromBody] long amount)
        {
            try
            {
                var service = new PaymentIntentService();
                var paymentIntent = await service.CreateAsync(new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
                {
                    Amount = amount,
                    Currency = "usd",
                    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> {"card", "us_bank_account"},
                    // AutomaticPaymentMethods = new PaymentIntentAutomaticPaymentMethodsOptions
                    // {
                    //     Enabled = true
                    // },
                });

                return Ok(new { ClientSecret = paymentIntent.ClientSecret });
            }
            catch (StripeException e)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { error = new { message = e.StripeError.Message }});
            }
        }
```

I have tried a bunch of different things but continue to get this response:

"errors":{"amount":["Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Int64' because the type requires a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) to deserialize correctly.\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON primitive value (e.g. string, number, boolean, null) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\nPath 'amount', line 1, position 10."]},

Comment: Please edit question and post code instead of images. Also provide class which you are trying to save.

Comment: `[FromBody] long amount` - `long (System.Int64)` is not what you have posted to controller. It expects class with properties as defined in JS `amount` variable.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - So what would need to be changed?

Comment: `[FromBody] long amount` to `[FromBody] RequestClass amount` where `RequestClass` is `class RequestClass  { public long amount { get; set;} }`. Or change JavaScript code to post NOT class but just amount value.

Comment: You are passing a `amount: 123` which is not a `long`, it is a key-value pair therefore your code cannot parse it. You should create an `Amount` class with a `value` property of `long` and change your code to `[FromBody] Amount amount` so that `amount.value` is the value you want from your client-side